# How to get cosmosdb emulator to expose port to nodejs application running on OSX?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I have read these instructions for running the cosmosdb emulator. [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-nodejs#disable-ssl-validation). In short I have virtual box VM running windows. I installed the cosmosdb emulator on that. I retrieved the IPv4 address from ipconfig.exe I can start the emulator with this command.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /AllowNetworkAccess /Key=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
```

I even deleted the data at  `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\CosmosDBEmulator\` as was suggested to do for first time startup. I created a nodejs application that looks like this.

app.js

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://10.0.2.15:8081/_explorer/index.html',
  timeout: 5000
}).then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log("success");
    console.log(response);
  }, e => {
    console.log("ERROR: ")
    console.log(e);
  })
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "daniel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0"
  }
}
```

However when I run `npm run start` for this node application outside the VM in OSX the request times out. I can however navigate to the website `https://10.0.2.15:8081/_explorer/index.html` within the VM. How do I make the nodejs application work so that it can call the cosmosdb emulator running in the VM from outside the VM in OSX? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please check if you can send request to the VM via port 8081?

Comment: Got it figured out. I set the port forwarding but I think the cm never got restarted which made it not work and then after I restarted it suddenly started working

Comment: Since you have solved the issue by yourself, please post your solution.

Comment: Ok sure I’ll do it tomorrow

Comment: Still going to do this. I havent had time. I will say. If any folks who work on cosmosdb emulator see this I would recommend going through the instructions as a mac/java user to setup cosmosdb emulator. There are many shortcomings in that documentation.